# Postgres Cluster exceeds temp_file_limit

Tags: postgresql

Recently, we are trying to migrate our database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. But, we didn't know that by default, tables in Potsgres are ot clustered. Now, when our data has increased so much, we want to CLUSTER our table like so

```
CLUSTER table USING idx_table;
```

But seems like my data is a lot (maybe), so that it produces

> SQL Error [53400]: ERROR: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit
> (8663254kB)

Since, its not resulted by a query, which I cannot tune it to perform better, Is there any solution for this?

If for example I am needed to increase my `temp_file_limit`, is it possible to increase it only for temporary? Since I'm only running this `CLUSTER` once.

Comment: You realize [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) is not permanent? Check on what [temp_file_limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html) is set to in `postgresql.conf and add as update to your question. See [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) for changing parameters on the fly. Or [set_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I thought that CLUSTER is permanent. since it is a permanent in `SQL SERVER`. sorry that it confused me. if its not permanent, then I think I should reconsider it, since periodically re-CLUSTER everything is quite a task. Thank you for pointing this out, and I think I will close my question then

Comment: You probably don't need to CLUSTER to begin with, do you have any proof that your queries would be faster if you use CLUSTER? You might be interested in this: https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wow this is really a good article. I thought that in SQL server, we must have the clustered index to make it performs better (this was how I was taught and read). This is really an eye opener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some important differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

Sybase SQL Server has been designed from INGRES in the beginning of the eighties when INGRES was using massively the concept of CLUSTERED indexes which means that table is organized as an index. The SQL Engine was designed especially to optimize the use of CLUSTERED index. That is the ways that SQL Server actually works...
When Postgres was designed, the use of CLUSTERED indexes disappeared.
When Postgres switched to the SQL language, an then be renamed to PostgreSQL nothing have changed to use CLUSTERED indexes.

So the use of CLUSTER tables in PostgreSQL is rarely optimal in execution plans. You have to prove individually for each table and for some queries involving those tables, if there is a benefit or not...

Another thing is that CLUSTERing a table in PostgreSQL is not the equivalent of MS SQL Server's CLUSTERED indexes...

More information about this will be find in my paper :

[PostgreSQL vs. SQL Server (MSSQL) – part 3 – Very Extremely Detailed Comparison](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/)

An especially in § : "6 – The lack of Clustered Index (AKA IOT)"

Comment: yes, it really seems that my understanding regarding `CLUSTER` in POSTGRE was wrong. this is really a good answer, but I dont know whether I can accept this as an answer or not, since my question seems off topic (since I had a wrong understanding with the POSTGRE which resulting in the question that I have)

Comment: It is why I wrote many papers,, but the main part in french, comparing PostGreSQL vs SQL Server... The recent ones are on http://mssqlserver.fr (french and english) and the old ones are on https://blog.developpez.com/sqlpro/

Comment: I suggest you can and should accept the answer. It may not be what you expected or desired, but it explains a concept you had incorrect and why you have problems. IMHO that is a correct, valuable, and usable answer. Any future questioner with the same problem/misconception will have their question answered. Again not a desirable one but certainly a definitive one.